# How to link libcurl with Qt6 for Android

Tags: qt, cmake, libcurl, qt6

In our CMakeLists.txt we've got:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
```

which works great for Debian native compiles.

When targeting Android, however, we get:

```
Could NOT find CURL
```

What can I do to link `libcurl` in a Qt6 Android environment (NDK)?

Comment: Well, do you have an Android build of libcurl to link to?

Comment: Also, Qt has an entire subsystem dedicated to making HTTP requests so not sure why you would bother with libcurl.

Comment: The design goals can't be concisely summarized.  I'd still like to know how to link libcurl, but I am starting to think you are right - Qt's facilities are the superior option.

Comment: You start by compiling libcurl for android and pointing CMake at it.

Comment: I've spent about 3 hours so far trying to setup a curl build environment.  This is not easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Botje's suggestion, I gave up `curl` in favor of Qt's facilities.  Now  using QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, and in limited scenarios QCoro 3rd party library.

On one hand this does not technically answer the question.

On the other, it nods to Qt's strengths - to provide curl-like (and so many other) facilities and Qt manages your cross platform concerns.  This was the superior option for me.